# Getting a error TypeError: color.charAt is not a function in C:/...../node_modules/@material-ui/core/styles/colorManipulator.js:148

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

Here is a link to the screenshot of the error : https://drive.google.com/open?id=1HL-Fy1M4tHp9qMUpt88PzOfI10AHHem- .

This is the code portion where colors are used.

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      light: '#33c9dc',
      main: '#00bcd4',
      dark: '#008394',
      contrastText: '#fff'
    },
    secondary: {
      light: '#ff6333',
      main: '#ff3d00',
      dark: '#b22a00',
      contrastText: '#fff'
    }
  },
  typography: {
    useNextVariants: true
  },
  form: {
    textAlign: "center"
  },
  image: {
    margin: "10px auto 10px auto"
  },
  pageTitle: {
    margin: "10px auto 10px auto"
  },
  textField: {
    margin: "10px auto 10px auto"
  },
  button: {
    marginTop: 20,
    position: "relative"
  },
  customError: {
    color: "red",
    fontSize: "0.8rem",
    marginTop: 5
  },
  progress: {
    position: "absolute"
  }
});
```

I already tried changing the colors from hexadecimal to rgb values, it didn't work.

Comment: Exactly same as you, are you also following this great tutorial? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m_u6P5k0vP0 exact same code ;)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

my solution to this problem is to put all styling objects inside another object leaving out the (palette) object, and spread out only that object that does not contain the (palette)

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
      primary: {
        light: '#33c9dc',
        main: '#00bcd4',
        dark: '#008394',
        contrastText: '#fff'
      },
      secondary: {
        light: '#ff6333',
        main: '#ff3d00',
        dark: '#b22a00',
        contrastText: '#fff'
      }
    },

    // the object to be spread
    spreadThis: {
       typography: {
        useNextVariants: true
      },
      form: {
        textAlign: "center"
      },
      image: {
        margin: "10px auto 10px auto"
      },
      pageTitle: {
        margin: "10px auto 10px auto"
      },
      textField: {
        margin: "10px auto 10px auto"
      },
      button: {
        marginTop: 20,
        position: "relative"
      },
      customError: {
        color: "red",
        fontSize: "0.8rem",
        marginTop: 5
      },
      progress: {
        position: "absolute"
      }
    }
});
```

now you would do this in the styles object

```
const style = theme => ({
  ...theme.spreadThis
});
```

hope this works out for you too!
good luck

Comment: Yes that works for me but i didn't understand how it does work

Comment: i try it in me code also, where i need to use the style object?

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had an empty object in my palette:

```
export default {
  breakpoints: {...},
  text: {
    primary: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87)",
    secondary: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.54)",
    disabled: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.38)",
    hint: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.38)"},
  divider: {}, // This was the issue, Either remove or put values in
  background: {
    paper: "#fff",
    default: "#fafafa",
    test: "#616161"
  },
};
```

It didn't effect any of the core, style or icon libraries in any way but I was hitting the same error as you for ages! Removing this sorted out the issue for me.